# Programmatically checking checkboxes in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I've got a VueJS application which filters items based on a number of checkbox items like a category filter for a shop.

When a user clicks a checkbox, we fire off an API request and a list of updated items is returned. The URL is also updated with a query string representing the checkbox that they have selected.

If a user navigates to a query stringed URL we want to have the checkboxes relating to the filters in the query string checked. That way if there is a page refresh, all the same checkboxes are checked.

We've done this so far using an `if(window.location.search)` and then parsing that query string, adding the parsed query string into an object. Passing that object down into the child component as a prop then setting the model the checkboxes are bound to to the query string object on update.

This works and is fine. The issue is theres stuttering and flashing of the checkboxes. You click the checkbox, it initially unchecks after selecting, the when the API response comes back, it select. Not very good for UX. I'm assuming this is because we're modifying the model the checkboxes are bound to while also trying to update it on checkbox click.

So I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing this please and if someone else has tackled a similar issue.

I've attached some code below, but as its spread across multiple components its quite hard to display here.

Thanks

```html
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(filter, index) in filters" v-bind:key="index">
      <input type="checkbox" name="filters" v-model="checked" v-on:change="changeItems">{{filter.filterName}}
    </li>

    {{checked}}
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        checked: []
      }
    },
    props: [
      'filters',
      'checkedFilters' //passed object of filters in query string
    ],
    updated: function() {
      this.checked = this.checkedFilters
    },
    methods: {
      changeItems: function (){
        this.$emit('change-items', this.checked)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using vue-router? Is this a fully client-side driven app, or is there a fair bit of server rendering?

Comment: Not using vue router. The api response is thing handled by the server. The rest is client side.

Comment: Where's the callback for the `change-items` event?  Also, should the `v-model` be bound to a the parent `checked` property rather than a child property like `filter.checked`? What's the type of the items in `filters`?